# How to install Qgis 3.4.6 LTR in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: ubuntu

I am facing difficulty in installing programs in Ubuntu especially the Qgis program. If anyone can explain the logic behind running scripts to install a program by the terminal it would be really helpful.

Comment: Please provide your attempt, what you've tried so far, where you have failed.

Comment: I just followed some youtube tutorial. But I got to install 2.18 so I removed it. I need 3.4 LTR

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need for ubuntu-18.x cosmic:
first you have to tell ubuntu a new package source
- $sudo add-apt-repository "deb     https://qgis.org/debian cosmic main"
- $sudo add-apt-repository "deb-src https://qgis.org/debian cosmic main"

then add the right pgp key
- $wget -O - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2017.gpg.key | gpg --import
- $gpg --fingerprint CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
- $gpg --export --armor CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45 | sudo apt-key add -

if everything is ok you can install **QGis**
- $sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass